# How to correctly forward to Spring logout URL from GWT UI?

Tags: gwt, spring-security, logout

I built a small sample application combining Spring Security and GWT besides a few other things. You can find it at:

https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-scala

Login and authentication are working fine. In the resulting GWT page, I inserted a Logout link. It should point to the Spring Security logout link. I used the [following GWT code](https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-scala/blob/master/web/src/main/java/de/hpfsc/web/parent.java#L158):

```
Anchor logoutLink = new Anchor("Logout");
logoutLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.Location.assign("j_spring_security_logout");
  }
});
```

If the user clicks the link, the session is terminated and the user is logged out. However, the user is not forwarded to the login page. How can I achieve that? As far as I see, I can't forward him to another URL after j_spring_security_logout.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you using a `ClickHandler` with an `Anchor`? Isn't `setHref` enough?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer That's true, I also changed that, but it wasn't the solution the overall problem. https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-scala/commit/289cb8430834c092d35ac5461621f60f7abec0a0#L0R157

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify logout url in your spring security configuration

```
<http auto-config='true'>
...
<logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
...
</http>
```

Comment: That did the trick. I put /spring_security_login as logout-success-url and it works now as expected: https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-scala/commit/289cb8430834c092d35ac5461621f60f7abec0a0#L1R16

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar kind of issue though I was getting 404 on j_spring_security_logout page and wasted too much time on finding the solution. Thought of sharing here in case someone is facing similar issue. I had to change

```
Window.Location.assign("j_spring_security_logout");
```

to

```
Window.Location.replace(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"j_spring_security_logout");
```

and the issue was resolved.